# How to send boost values while querying in elastic search?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I need to add a search relevancy score to a particular query in elastic search.
How can I add a boosting score for a particular filed while querying?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html
it shows you how to add boosting to a field at query time. For example

```
{
    "query_string" : {
    "fields" : ["content", "name^5"],
    "query" : "this AND that OR thus",
    "use_dis_max" : true
}
```

Note however there is potential for this to slow down your query considerably so I would test it or use boosting in the mapping file.